# How can I use methods in the SO files produced by mono AOT in my C program?

Tags: c#, c, mono, shared-libraries, aot

I have used mono --aot=full to compile a small program I wrote under linux and it has produced a .so file. I read up on these and found that they are actually libraries and not executables, and I was wondering how I could link to these libraries in a c program so that I could use the methods I wrote in c sharp in the c program?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--aot=full` switch product is an .so file that has the pre-compiled bytecodes. It depends on platform and run native instructions but it still needs the CLR (Mono Runime) to do the thread & task managements and other .NET platform operations.

If what you need it to call Native (C#) methods from your non-managed (C/C++) program you are looking for these resources:

- [Native interop rules for mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries) This link shows how to call native (C/C++) methods from your C# program, but it also have all the type compatibility you will need for your endeavor;
- [Embedding Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono) This link shows how to start the Mono Runtime from within your C/C++ code and how to call managed code after that;